# Padding can not applied to the right side of the header

Tags: html, css, padding

I just started learning CSS. The problem is that I want to add padding to the header but even though padding is applied on the left side it isn't applied to the right side.

How can I solve it and why is it happening?

The CSS code-related `header`, header `image`, and `section` are below. Section `a` is the Youtube part.

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html{
    font-size: 10px;
}

body{
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.5;
    background-color: #333;
    color: azure;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

p{
    padding: 1.6rem 0;
}

header{
    height: 46rem;
    padding: 2rem;
}

header .bg-image{
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url(images/01.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    height: 46rem;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0.5;
    z-index: -1;
}

header h1{
    padding: 16rem;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}

.btn{
    display: inline-block;
    background: #333;
    border : 1px solid #666 ;
    margin: .5rem 0;
    color: azure;
    padding: 1.6rem 3.2rem;
    transition: all 0.4s;
}

.btn:hover{
    background-color: azure;
    color: #333;
}

#section-b{
    padding:2rem ;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is happening since image part is absolute element.

Please update css like this.

```css
header .bg-image{
    position:absolute;
    background-image: url(images/01.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    height:46rem;
    left: 2rem;
    right: 2rem;
    opacity: 0.5;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: could you explain in detail?